# make a clean background with an image with Tkinter in python

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm currently trying to build an app in python with Tkinter, and I'm trying to use an image as a background. I've been able to do that, but when I add other widgets (like frames and labels), their own background overlaps the first one, and the result is not really pleasant. I've search a bit, but I didn't find a way to avoid this. Is it possible ?
This is my code :

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1280x720")
root.update()

background_img = Image.open("./background.jpg")
background_img = background_img.resize((root.winfo_width(),root.winfo_height()), Image.ANTIALIAS)
background_tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(background_img)

background_label = tk.Label(root, image=background_tkimg)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.place(anchor="c", relx=.5, rely=.5)

title_label = tk.Label(frame, text="TITLE")
button1 = tk.Button(frame, text="button 1")
button2 = tk.Button(frame, text="button 2")
button3 = tk.Button(frame, text="button 3")

title_label.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=30)
button1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
button2.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20, pady=10)
button3.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=20, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

And when I run it, I have this window :
[image: screen of the window]

Comment: Unfortunately, the only way to avoid this is to use a `Canvas` and display all other widgets with help of `.create_window` and similar methods.

Comment: I have updated the code in my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This effect can be achieved by using the Tkinter canvas and placing the widgets using `.create_window()`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1280x720")
root.update()

background_img = Image.open("./background.jpg")
background_img = background_img.resize((root.winfo_width(),root.winfo_height()), Image.ANTIALIAS)
background_tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(background_img)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack(expand = True, fill = "both")
canvas.create_image(0,0, image = background_tkimg, anchor = "nw")

root.update()
canvas_height = canvas.winfo_height()
canvas_width = canvas.winfo_width()

title_label = canvas.create_text((canvas_width//2), (canvas_height//2) - 25, fill = "white", text="TITLE")
button1 = tk.Button(canvas, text="button 1")
button2 = tk.Button(canvas, text="button 2")
button3 = tk.Button(canvas, text="button 3")

canvas.create_window((canvas_width//2) - 75, (canvas_height//2) + 25 , window = button1)
canvas.create_window((canvas_width//2), (canvas_height//2) + 25, window = button2)
canvas.create_window((canvas_width//2) + 75, (canvas_height//2) + 25, window = button3)

root.mainloop()
```

The label has been replaced with `canvas.create_text()` for a transparent background. The positioning isn't the same as the original, it's just based off approximate offsets from the centre.

This produces this result:

[image: Code result]

Comment: So I suppose it is impossible to use Frames with this method. Because the structure of my app is actually more complicated, so I don't think I will be able to do it without frames. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @larticho The frames won't be transparent, but you could work out which part of the background the frame covers and set that as the background of the frame, but that is quite a lot of effort. If you think this answer could help others please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the only way to avoid this is to use a `Canvas` and display all other widgets with help of `.create_window` and similar methods. Moreover, you won't be able to use `pack`, `place` and `grid` geometry managers. Instead, you need to calculate coordinates from the top left corner of the `Canvas` and create other objects according to them.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


W, H = 1280, 720
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("{}x{}".format(W, H))
root.resizable(False, False)
root.update()

background_img = Image.open("./background.jpg").resize((W, H), Image.ANTIALIAS)
background_tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(background_img)

canv = tk.Canvas(root)
canv.create_image(0, 0, image=background_tkimg, anchor="nw")
canv.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

canv.create_text(W / 2, H / 2, fill="white", text="TITLE")
for i in range(1, 4):
    canv.create_window(W / 2 - 200 + i * 100, H / 2 + 65, window=tk.Button(canv, text="button {}".format(i)))

root.mainloop()
```

Note that I have changed the "TITLE" text color (with `fill` argument) to white, otherwise it is hard to see it on the dark background. Here is a screenshot (with a similar background).

[image: The screenshot]