# Tkinter remove widget background while using custom image background

Tags: python, tkinter

[widget grey background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8H7B.png) So, I have used a custom image background for my app, but when I seem to use it. I can still see the grey background of the labels and the other widgets that I have used. Please help me, you can look at the picture below.

Comment: It's not possible to give tkinter widgets a transparent background, but you can try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63488125/7519434)

Comment: Also, I have just answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66103900/14094985), you could check that approach as well.